# Text in <pre> tag is cutting half in print view

Tags: html, css, printing, pre

I have a pre tag in my code which is coming dynamically. The text in pre tag is cutting into half at the end of the page in print version. It is working fine if I use other tags like P or Div instead of PRE. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add a style to "PRE" like:

```
<style>
    PRE {
        white-space: normal;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Alternatively wrapped in @media print { ... } if you don't want it to affect screen view

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your quick response. I tried it but no luck.